# how to fit a censored univariate distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics

A random variable (RV) consist of the frequency of successes for each trial, for example:

> Assuming independence of each trial, let X be the number of trials that it took for N students to pass a statistics test:
>
> X = {1,2,3,4,5,6,**7 or above**}
>
> Freq = {31,27,14,11,9,4,8}

In R how can I fit a binomial distribution to this RV. I tried *fitdistr* but I do not know how to deal with the 7+ frequency.

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify/explain your example a bit more please? If I'm reading this correctly, there are 31 cases with 1 success out of (X), 27 cases with 2 successes out of (X), ... and 8 cases with >= 7 successes out of (X). You want to estimate the probability of success.  But what is the number of attempts per trial?  Or, if I'm misunderstanding, please enlighten me ...

Comment: An example: assuming independence of each trial, 31 students passed the statistics test after the 1st attempt, 27 after the 2nd attempt, ... 8 students after 7+  attempts.

Comment: Then I don't think this is a binomial distribution. I think you should consider a geometric or *negative* binomial distribution.  Can you edit your question to include the contents of your comment please?

Comment: Thank you Ben, I have edited the question. Agree I should consider a geometric for a sample with no replacement, but don't quite get why assuming replacement you suggest a negative binomial instead of a binomial. Either case, my question would still be how to go about the "7 or above" case.

Comment: I was wrong about negative binomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up data

```
dd <- data.frame(X = 1:7,
    freq=c(31,27,14,11,9,4,8))
```

Set up distribution function: the hardest part here is that there's a bit of fussing because R defines the domain of the geometric distribution starting from 0 rather than 1 ...

```
dcgeom <- function(x, prob, cens=7, log=FALSE) {
    r <- ifelse(x>=cens-1,
           pgeom(x-1, prob, log.p = log, lower.tail=FALSE),
           dgeom(x-1, prob, log = log))
    return(r)
}
NLLfun <- function(prob) {
    -sum(dd$freq*dcgeom(dd$X, prob=prob, log=TRUE))
}
library(bbmle)
m1 <- mle2(NLLfun,start=list(prob=0.5))
```

Results:

```
par(las=1,bty="l") ## cosmetic
plot(freq~X,data=dd,ylim=c(0,45))
points(1:6,sum(dd$freq)*dgeom(0:5,prob=coef(m1)),col=2,pch=16,
       type="b")
points(7,sum(dd$freq)*pgeom(6,prob=coef(m1),lower.tail=FALSE),
  col=2,pch=16)
```

[image]